# uninitialized constant CustomerBill::CustomerBillLineItem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created an association between `customer_bill` and `customer_bill_line_item` as follows:

```
class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_bill_line_items_attributes
  has_many :customer_bill_line_items, :dependent =>:destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_bill_line_items, :allow_destroy => true
end

class CustomerBillLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_bill_id 
  belongs_to :customer_bill, :foreign_key => "customer_bill_id"
end
```

When I enter a form in create mode, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant CustomerBill::CustomerBillLineItem

Extracted source (around line #66):

63:                             <%end%>
64:                            
65:                            
66:             <%= f.fields_for :customer_bill_line_items do |builder| %>
67:             <%= render 'customer_bill_line_item_fields', :f => builder %>
68:             <%end%>
```

The full stack trace is given in the comment.

Is there an association that must be made in `customer_bills_controller` like`@customer_bill.customer_bill_line_items`??

Guidance required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a link to a gist that shows the stack trace?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NNTbFZV5 :- this is the entire trace of the event

Comment: can you also include the following file on the question and highlight line 66 `app/views/customer_bills/_form.html.erb`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2Yx32tz7

Comment: sorry, a quick look at the code doesn't raise any questions. perhaps someone has some other thoughts.

Comment: Are both of these classes defined in the same file? Rails won't instantiate both classes by default if they are.

Comment: No max they are in different files. customer bill in customer_bill.rb and line item in customer_bill_line_item.rb

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've shown, unfortunately I'm not on a machine with Rails on it so I can't replicate this at the moment. If no-one has figured it out by then, I'll take another look at this issue when I get home tonight.

Comment: `attr_accesible :customer_bill_id` seems to have a typo; it should be `accessible` with two 's'. If the code is fine on your end, could you edit the question and correct it please?

Comment: Thank you for notifying the mistake, i have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quickly threw an example app together to prove what you were doing was right, you can check it out here: https://github.com/Bram--/customer_bill which works fine.
Just make sure before you spin it up you have a Customer Bill & CustomerBillLineItems:

```
c = CustomerBill.create name: 'Name'
CustomerBillLineItem.create name: 'Line Item A', price: '1.00', customer_bill_id: c.id
CustomerBillLineItem.create name: 'Line Item B', price: '2.00', customer_bill_id: c.id
```

What versions are you using, is there anything else we're not seeing in the above code?

Hope the example helps, otherwise drop me a line.

Comment: i am using rails 3.2.10. Actually there was a very silly mistake in bill.rb. had added 'customer_bill_line_item_attibutes' twice in 'attr_accessible'. two people working on same file led to this error.

Thanks for the insight you have provided. helped in understanding codes better.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> Is there an association that must be made in customer_bills_controller like@customer_bill.customer_bill_line_items??

Per our working mockup by Novae **it does not** (from customer_bills_controller.rb, [Novae's mock](https://github.com/Bram--/customer_bill)):

```
class CustomerBillsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @customer_bill = CustomerBill.last
  end

  def update
    @customer_bill = CustomerBill.find params[:id]
    @customer_bill.update_attributes!(params[:customer_bill])

  redirect_to @customer_bill, flash: { notice: 'Updated' }
  end
end
```

To robotically point out a difference, in his `customer_bill_line_item.rb` model Novae includes more `CustomerBillLineItem` attributes in `attr_accessible` (from app/models/):

```
class CustomerBillLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_bill_id, :name, :price
  belongs_to :customer_bill, :foreign_key => "customer_bill_id"
end
```

I am unable to envision how these result in your error, but they are what I was able to find.

Comment: Actually there was a very silly mistake in bill.rb. had added 'customer_bill_line_item_attibutes' twice in 'attr_accessible' of customer bill.rb. two people working on same file led to this error.

Thanks for clearing my doubt about adding `@customer_bill.customer_bill_line_items` in controller. helped in understanding the code better. +1 for the answer

Answer (score 2):

the error is telling you what the problem is. There is no class CustomerBill::CustomerBillLineItem that can be found.

1: I'm assuming your not building instances of customer_bill_line_item in the customer_bills#new action else you would be seeing that same error there.

Please confirm by checking that your are building instances of customer_bill_line_item on @customer_bill in the new action with something like

```
3.times{@customer_bill.customer_bill_line_items.build}
```

If you get the same error again but on the line of your controller build it confirms what the error is saying that is it cant find the class CustomerBillLineItem through CustomerBill

I suspect a typo in the file name of the class CustomerBillLineItem. Make sure your class is in a file named customer_bill_line_item.rb and is in your models folder and not nested in any other folder. Possibly scope is an issue here too.

The bottom line is CustomerBillLineItem is not named or placed correctly and that is why your getting that error which is telling you it cant find said class.